# Drop down menu not working after adding jQuery Datepicker

Tags: php, bootstrap-datepicker

Dropdown in my navigation bar not working after adding datepicker header files and jQuery code.

My datepicker header files:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Navigation bar having dropdown which is not working

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown d-none d-xl-inline-block">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="UserDropdown" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="profile-text pro">Hello, &nbsp;  <?php echo $username;?> </span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right navbar-dropdown" aria-labelledby="UserDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item mt-2"  href='studentprofile.php?username=<?php  echo $username ?>'>
            View profile
        </a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href='changepassword.php?username=<?php  echo $username ?>'>
            Change Password
        </a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="login.php">
            Sign Out
        </a>
    </div>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
// When the document is ready
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#from').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,  
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    });  
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: are both using different version of jQuery? If yes, please edit your question with more code having the script tag of both

Comment: I would guess datepicker requires jQuery, so jQuery needs to go first. Check your devtools console, are there errors?

Comment: 2 errors   Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at bootstrap-datepicker.js:13
    at bootstrap-datepicker.js:15
vendor.bundle.addons.js:47429 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined
    at vendor.bundle.addons.js:47429
    at vendor.bundle.addons.js:47429

Comment: Did you try moving jQuery first, as I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your JQuery to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```